# Regex expression for a repeating non-consecutive number

Tags: regex

I need to check if a string matches a certain pattern. The pattern is:

```
"B-n,I-n"
```

Where n is an integer. Is there a good regex for this?

Edit: The number after "B-" and after "I-" must be the same.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if a particular string is in the form "letter B followed by dash, followed by a number ..." or are you trying to determine if the overall set of strings makes a pattern?

Comment: The first one. Sorry for my poor phrasing. The value after the B and the I have to be equal.

Comment: what if the input is `"B-1,I-1" "B-3,I-3"`..Is it valid..2 is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that n is any positive integer and You need to capture the quotes as well it would be like this:

```
^"B-([0-9]+),I-\1"$
```

The () makes the subpattern to be captured, and then \1 says to regex engine to match the same what was captured in the first pattern.

You can test [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Regexes find patterns in a single string.  You're asking to search many strings to see if they follow a pattern.  You'll need to write code.  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave every time you have a problem that happens to involve strings.

Answer (score 0):

This will match all of the above:

```
[A-Z]-[a-z0-9],[A-Z]-[a-z0-9]
```

It will also match:

G-z,P-f

Etc.

Comment: that would not work..he wants to match input line `G-n,P-m` where `n` and `m` are numbers and `n==m`